# Remove onClickListener after clicking button

Tags: android, android-intent, onclicklistener

I want to create something if i type for example "abc" in a `TextField` it will open an activity. if i type in something else i don't want it to open the activity. 
I already made something, it works the first time (it sais wrong if you haven't entered a valid input and it opens a page if you enter "abc". I want this system with multiple options i used "abc" and "bbb". It works the first time, but if i go back and enter something else it opens the same page as the first try. 
Perhaps i have to disable the `OnClickListener`, but how?

this is my MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
   final EditText textedit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if ("abc".equals(textedit.getText().toString())) 
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen1.class);
                        startActivity(intent);


                    }
                });                
            if ("bbb".equals(textedit.getText().toString()))
                button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen2.class);
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });
            else 
                button.setText("wrong pass");

        }
    });
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

"Schoen1" and "Schoen2" are my pages to open.
Thank you!

Comment: Check my answer. It should be all you need. You just have to move your `if` statements inside your `onClick` and no need for the extra `listener`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the `onClickListener()` is already set. What you need to do is move that code inside your `onClick()`

```
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 if ("abc".equals(textedit.getText().toString())) 
                 {
                      Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen1.class);
                      startActivity(intent);
                 }
                 else  if ("bbb".equals(textedit.getText().toString()))
                 {
                       Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen2.class);
                       startActivity(i);
                 }
```

Comment: @user2320105 Where are these `flag` variables? I see, from the above answer. I don't see what good those flags are doing. If you use my answer you shouldn't need any `flags`

Answer (score 0):

You have two `onClickListener`s inside of an `onClickListener` for starters. Get rid of the inner set and try adding a flag so that once your `Intent` runs, it doesn't run again the next time. You will need to reset the flags at some point so that the `Intents` don't only open once ever.

```
boolean flag1 = true;
boolean flag2 = true;

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if ("abc".equals(textedit.getText().toString()) && flag1) {
            flag1 = false;
            Intent intent = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen1.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }  else if ("bbb".equals(textedit.getText().toString()) && flag2) {
            flag2 = false;
            Intent i = new Intent (MainActivity.this, Schoen2.class);
            startActivity(i);

        } else {
            button.setText("wrong pass");
        }

    }
});
```

Code not tested.

Comment: i tried your method but i keep on getting "The final local variable flag2 cannot be assigned, since it is defined in an enclosing type" and the same at flag 1 at the flag1 = false part. How to fix this?

Comment: You can't reassign a `final` variable. That's why they are `final`

Comment: @codeMagic - You can't reassign a final variable but you can change the value.

Comment: @user2320105 - This should just be in your onCreate method. If it's a problem, try getting rid of the final keyword. I've found though that if I have a variable that I want to use in a listener or something, it needs to be declared as final and it needs to be declared above the listener.

Comment: No, you can't change the value of a `final` variable in this way

Comment: To use any GUI element by name in a submethod of a method (as in a listener within onCreate), the keyword final needs to be in front of it. This ensures the pointer to that variable does not get changed. I confused the use of final for Objects with use for a regular variable, such as a int, boolean, etc. I will fix my answer to reflect this. Apologies, codeMagic.

Comment: But you still can't access it in this way. It needs to be a member variable. Why is the `flag` even needed?

Comment: @user2320105 Anytime! If this answered your question, could you select it as the answer?